# Как добавить определенную тайм зону datetime.now()

Tags: python, python-3.x, дата, timezone

В python 3.10 есть zoneinfo и куча предложений как добавить тайм зону в дату время вроде:

```
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

dt = datetime(2020, 10, 31, 12, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("America/Los_Angeles"))
print(dt)
```

и вывод получается требуемый, только как получить в этом формате текущее время тишина. Есть у кого идеи на этот счет?

Comment: А что такое текущее время для произвольной даты `datetime`?

Comment: Скорее это текущее время - datetime.now()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

tz = timezone("America/Los_Angeles")
dt = datetime.now(tz=tz)

print(dt)
```

Comment: Не уверен, что автора, задающего вопрос про zoneinfo, устроит использование pytz

Comment: @andreymal Кажется, с zoneinfo должно работать в точности так же.

Answer (score 0):

Благодарю за помощь, можно в однострочное решение

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

time = datetime.now(pytz.timezone("Africa/Nairobi"))
```